# PHP script dynamic display of files in directory based on user privileges?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, path, directory

Ive made the following script to display files from a directory if user is signed in:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("path/file.php");

if (!empty($_SESSION[username]))
{echo "You <b>$_SESSION[username]</b> are registered.";

$dirPath = dir('includes/path/');
$docArray = array();
while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false)
{
  if ((substr($file, -3)=="pdf") || (substr($file, -3)=="doc"))
  {
     $docArray[ ] = trim($file);
  }
}
$dirPath->close();
sort($docArray);
$c = count($docArray);
foreach($docArray as $filename)
{
    echo "<div><a href=\"./includes/path/$filename\">Download '$filename'</a></div>";
    echo "<br/>";
} 
 include('logout.php');
}

else
{echo "somethingsomething";

include('login.php');
}
?>
```

In the members table there are two columns MSV and LTP with possible values 0, 1. Also  I have to directories /path/LTP and /path/MSV.

I would need an addition to the script that if a user has privileges to LTP or/and MSV, the files would be displayed accordingly.

Comment: You don't show any code dealing with your members table (I assume it's a MySQL database), and I assume the `path/MSV` / `path/LTP` part is going to be the `$dirPath`? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, all files are stored in mysql database in a members table. Users are inserted manually username|password|company|LTP|MSV.

Comment: and the file path is currently /includes/published/ this should be split up into two directories /includes/MSV and /includes/LTP/

Answer (score 0):

You will need stored into `$_SESSION` the value of the fields `LTP` and `MSV` and try somethig like this in the php file that your are using to read those folder

read LTP folder

```
if(!empty($_SESSION[LTP])){
 //code to read LTP folder
}else{
//Cannot read LTP folder 
}
```

read MSV folder

```
if(!empty($_SESSION[MSV])){
//code to read MSV folder
}else{
//Cannot read MSV folder
}
```

Assuming `0` is deny acces and `1` is grant permission to read

Comment: The values are stored in a mysql database. All members are manually inserted username\

Comment: @user1185197 You know how to get those values from mysql and stored them into a $_SESSION???

Answer (score 0):

Query your database for the user, and build in logic after you fetch your row.

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['username']);
$query = "SELECT `LTP`, `MSV` FROM `members` WHERE `username`='".$username."'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

if ($row['MSV'] == '1') {
    //provide access to MSV files here.
}

if ($row['LTP'] == '1') {
    //provide access to LTP files here.
}
```

Note that the `die` statement is for debugging and is not graceful enough for production use.